# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException exception while trying to call a webservice from my android java application?

Tags: java, android, web-services

Hi am new to Android java development and am trying to call a java webservice from my android java application. When am trying to run this application am getting one exception which says android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. I didn't know why this error..?? anyway am stuck with this error. I had googled for this a lot but can't find an exact solution..can anyone plz help..?my code snippet below.

```
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
        SoapObject so = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

After done the debugging i think these lines of code `androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
            SoapObject so = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;` is making problems.
The code `envelope.bodyIn` giving me a null value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the AsyncTask, which will prevent the hassle of creating your own thread. Make network call in doInBackGround method

Code

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    new DownloadImageTask().execute(data);
 }
 class Data {
      String namespace;
      String method;
 }

 private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<data, Void, SoapObject> {

 protected SoapObject doInBackground(Data... data) {
    //make your network call and return SoapObject
 }


protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject obj) {
    //process the Soap Object returned
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dot net Webservice so you add in request .net true
in below line of

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

//Add Here this Line

```
 envelope.dotNet = true;
```

//then your code

```
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

//Add this for debug

```
HttpTransportSE.debug = true;  //this is optional, use it if you don't want to use a packet sniffer to check what the sent message was (httpTransport.requestDump)
```

//as your code

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
    SoapObject so = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

After adding thie line your request come succesfully ..the accept the answer and Upvote

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a network request on a different thread. The request will block your main thread which will decrease the responsiveness of the application. See the [exception documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). Another link tells you the standard approach for this.

From this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)

> The recommended approach is to create a child thread and do most of
>   your work there. This keeps the main thread (which drives the user
>   interface event loop) running and prevents the system from concluding
>   that your code has frozen. Since such threading usually is
>   accomplished at the class level, you can think of responsiveness as a
>   class problem. (Compare this with basic performance, which was
>   described above as a method-level concern.)