# Web Service using KSOAP Connection Error in android

Tags: android, web-services

I am trying to connect to a .net webservice from android using ksoap2 but i am gettingnull output as `"null°F"`;.please find the  log file below and  help me in clearing this. I use KSOAP from webservice

```
package com.example.webservice;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WebService extends Activity {
       private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
       private final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
       private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
       private final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_service);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Result);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String result=getFarenheit(et.getText().toString());
            tv.setText(result+"°F");
            }
        });
    }
    public String getFarenheit(String celsius){
        SoapObject request= new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo celsuiusPI= new PropertyInfo();
        celsuiusPI.setName("Celsius");
        celsuiusPI.setValue(celsius);
        celsuiusPI.setType(double.class);
        request.addProperty(celsuiusPI);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope (SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try{
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("WebService output", response.toString());
            return response.toString();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //return null;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_web_service, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Can someone tell the fault in my program

Comment: I have post a full example working with Android 2_4:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13829138/1895995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a String input at your asynctask class definition. But you did't give that string to your asynctask class. 
Two way:

1-Remove String parameter from definition

```
public class servicecall extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
```

|

to

|

```
 public class servicecall extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
```

2-Give some string to your asynctask class

```
new servicecall().execute("Some string");
```

Answer (score 1):

A null pointer exception is way to generic you have to specify/give more debug information.
Also your URL, might be wrong, try adding `?wsdl` at the end of it.

Comment: I also think this will be the solution. Because KSOAP need to get URL of wsdl.