# Fail to connect android to web service

Tags: android, web-services

Hi I am experimenting on android to web service connection. In order to do this, the steps I have done are:

1. find free web service: http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx
2. create a basic activity on Android Studio
3. change the Manifest file to have permission to use internet by adding the following line:

   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
4. add the ksoap2 library
5. Try to consume the web service using the following code:

[declarations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1Lwj.png)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();
    property.setName("word");
    //property.setType(String.class);
    property.setValue("computer");
    request.addProperty(property);


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    Object response = null;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.getServiceConnection();

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tv.setText("success");
        response =  envelope.getResponse();
        response.toString();
        String resultData= response.toString();
        tv.setText(resultData);

    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, textView1 is not getting the result. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Note:
I use Android Studio with Gradle version 2.10

Comment: You need to use AsyncTask. Google and find how people have done it.

Comment: @Bhush_Techidiot: Thank you. you are right! apparantly I have to use AsysnTask. It was ok without AsyncTask for old versions.  However, if you only want to test your connection  you can add the following code to onCreate:  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); <br/>

Comment: This discussion really helped me:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969071/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-for-webservice-ksoap

Comment: @Bhush_Techidiot: I have finally tested the code using StrictMode, and it's working now. I am trying to implement it using AsyncTask now. However, I am having a hard time while trying to pass "web service method arguments" so that it can work in doinBackgroind method.

Comment: Please post your updated code.

Comment: @Bhush_Techidiot: I have updated the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052412/how-to-put-result-from-asynctask-doinbackground-from-different-class-to-textv

Comment: @Bhush_Techidiot: I have solved the problem. Thank you for your help. I want to accept your answer, but I dont know how to accept a coomment.

Comment: Update your code and I can post the same. Though, glad to know it helped.

Comment: Never mind. Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using AsyncTask for executing Webservices. Here's a sample -> [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException for webservice (ksoap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969071/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-for-webservice-ksoap)

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String TAG ="Vik";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
        task.execute(); 
    }

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            calculate();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
        }

    }

    public void calculate() 
    {
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
        String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
        String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";

        try { 
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            Request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            HttpTransportSE transport= new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();

            Log.i(TAG, "Result Celsius: " + resultString);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
        METHOD_NAME = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
        try { 
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            Request.addProperty("Fahrenheit", "100");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            HttpTransportSE transport= new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();

            Log.i(TAG, "Result Fahrenheit: " + resultString);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a routine for a ASP.Net web service:

```
public static SoapPrimitive callProcServiceForObject(String serviceMethod, String storedProc, String params) throws Exception {
    String NAMESPACE = "http://YourWebServiceURL.com";
    String METHOD_NAME = getMethodName(serviceMethod);
    String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
    String URL = "http://YourWebServiceURL.com";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    request.addProperty("sPassword", YourPassword);
    request.addProperty("sData", GlobalVars.serverDB);
    request.addProperty("sSP_Name", storedProc);
    request.addProperty("sParam", params);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    // Enable the below property if consuming .Net service
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, timeout);

    SoapObject returnable = null;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        returnable = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception("Msg:" + e.getMessage() + "; SP:" + storedProc + "; Params: " + params + "; Method:" + METHOD_NAME);
    }
    return returnable;
}
```

Reading the SOAP object:

```
SoapPrimitive response = callProcServiceForObject(storedProcedureName, params);
if (response != null) {
    String sResponse = response.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I cannot find the essence difference between your code and mine. Can you refer more to my code other than suggesting the new one? It will be really appreciated if you could experience my code with the related web service yourself and give the feedback that way.