# How to put result from "AsyncTask doInBackground from different class" to "TextView in MainActivity"

Tags: android, web-services, callback, textview

I am new to android. This question is a phase from my steps in experimenting with android apps and web service. I have asked a question before, which is in here: [Fail to connect android to web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985939/fail-to-connect-android-to-web-service).
Below is my Updated code,
my code in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Mytask mt = new Mytask();
        mt.execute();


    }

}
```

my code in Mytask:

```
public class Mytask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://services.aonaware.com/webservices/Define";
    private static final String URL = "http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Define";
    private static final String NAMESPACE =  "http://services.aonaware.com/webservices/";

    String resultData=null;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();
        property.setName("word");
        property.setType(String.class);
        property.setValue("computer");
        request.addProperty(property);
        Log.i("soap tobe", "----");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        Object response = null;
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.getServiceConnection();
            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("soap passed", "----"+response);
            response =  envelope.getResponse();
            resultData= response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("result passed", "----"+response.toString());

        return resultData;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("onPost passed", "----"+result);
    }

}
```

I got the result right in the "onPost passed" log. From here, how can I put the result into TextView in MainActivity?

Comment: Far too complicated seems to me the answer provided. In my project I'm using [Eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Simply create and post a new Event in your `onPostExecute` and catch it wherever you need to elsewhere in your app. It's a great tool I stumbled upon, and I gladly recommend it onward. The `Event` you create and post can and should be custom object of your own [it can contain far more complex data than just a string or two].

Comment: @Vucko what is complicated in the answer ? To be frank it is a very general approach that can be used in a lot of places. Such as communicating between activity and fragments etc While using libraries like Eventbus etc is always a great option but it should be used only after a good understanding of the building concepts otherwise developers will remain clueless about how things actually are working.

Comment: @varunkr I get your point. cool bro :)

Comment: @Vucko: Thank you for the help. Your answer will help me later on as a reference, when I  try to develop my skill by using library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use interface

1.) Create interface class in your asyncTask class.

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output);
}
```

2.) And declare interface AsyncResponse as a field in asyncTask class:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{
  public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  delegate.processFinish(result);
}
 }
```

3.) In your main Activity you need to implements interface AsyncResponse.

```
public class MainActivity implements AsyncResponse{
  MyAsyncTask asyncTask =new MyAsyncTask();



@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 //this to set delegate/listener back to this class
 asyncTask.delegate = (MyAsyncTask)this;

 //execute the async task 
 asyncTask.execute();
  }



//this override the implemented method from asyncTask
  void processFinish(String output){
     //Here you will receive the result fired from async class 
     //of onPostExecute(result) method.
   }
 }
```

**Edit**

```
public class Mytask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://services.aonaware.com/webservices/Define";
    private static final String URL = "http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Define";
    private static final String NAMESPACE =  "http://services.aonaware.com/webservices/";

    String resultData=null;
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();
        property.setName("word");
        property.setType(String.class);
        property.setValue("computer");
        request.addProperty(property);
        Log.i("soap tobe", "----");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        Object response = null;
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.getServiceConnection();
            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("soap passed", "----"+response);
            response =  envelope.getResponse();
            resultData= response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("result passed", "----"+response.toString());

        return resultData;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("onPost passed", "----"+result);
        delegate.processFinish(result);

    }

    public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
    }

}
```

And activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse{
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Mytask mt = new Mytask();
        mt.delegate = this;
        mt.execute();
    }

    void processFinish(String output){
        tv.setText(output); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to follow your code but apparently there is compile error when I try to implement AsyncResponse to MainActivity. Could it be because I have extends AppCompatActivity there? Can you please refer to my code, and add the necessary stuff there,other than giving a new code. Thank you in advance

Comment: I wrote implements Mytask.AsyncResponse instead since I created the interface inside Mytask class (pls correct me if I am wrong). Now there is a compile error in processFinish method. it says that the method clash with the other one. also attempting to assign weaker access privileges('packageLocal'); was 'public'

Comment: @Job I added the code for you, simply use it and tell me if it works !!

Comment: I am trying to make the method public now. by doing  public void processFinish(String output){
        //Here you will receive the result fired from async class
        //of onPostExecute(result) method.
        tv.setText(output);
    }

Comment: @Job ok so what is the problem?

Comment: no compile error now. but when I run the program it crashed. let me review it again. I will notify you the result.

Comment: @Job oh, ok, if you can't find the problem then post the crash. In any case do tell me if you were able to get this to work !!

Comment: finally it works. Apparantly, I forgot to add the INTERNET permission for this app. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Job great, and you should understand this technique well, coz it comes handy in many situations. Thanks for accepting the answer. Can you also upvote it. Helps with the reputation and score :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111147/discussion-between-job-and-varunkr).